# Color of svgs change to black on cloning group of svgs in fabricjs v1.5

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

In fabricjs v1.5, i load two different svgs with color red and stroke black. Now select any svg and click on "clone object" button, it's cloned correctly, but when I select both svgs and click on "clone group" button, color of the cloned group change to black. This is the issue with v1.5 only.

I changed to fabricjs v1.4 and tried the same, everythings works perfectly.

**Here is what I want in fabricjs v1.5**

[image: This is what I want with fabricjs v1.5]

**But, here is what I get in fabricjs v1.5**

[image: But I got this in fabricjs v1.5]

How to solve this issue in v1.5. You can try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/0fbefh52/13/

```
$('#duplicate-group').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

if(canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
    alert("yes");
  var actGrp = canvas.getActiveGroup();  
  actGrp.clone(function (clone) {
      clone.set({
          left: actGrp.left+Math.random()*10,
          top: actGrp.top+Math.random()*10
      });
    clone.setCoords();
    canvas.add(clone); 
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug of 1.5.0 release.
This has been solved in 1.6.0rc.

The group was delegating fill properties to child objects.
Please just update to latest version and you will solve, or otherwise apply just those changes to your version:
https://github.com/sapics/fabric.js/commit/e07350c9e7cae222c8cf1b2b6196bd6c9b6d1151

That have been merged in official release

This is a patch file:

```
From e07350c9e7cae222c8cf1b2b6196bd6c9b6d1151 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: sapics <gv.nishino@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 9 Apr 2015 14:45:32 +0900
Subject: [PATCH] fix group initialization

---
 src/shapes/group.class.js | 51 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------
 test/unit/group.js        | 12 ++++++++++-
 2 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)

diff --git a/src/shapes/group.class.js b/src/shapes/group.class.js
index c6f1d65..4f394d7 100644
--- a/src/shapes/group.class.js
+++ b/src/shapes/group.class.js
@@ -52,11 +52,19 @@
      * Constructor
      * @param {Object} objects Group objects
      * @param {Object} [options] Options object
+     * @param {Boolean} [isAlreadyGrouped] if true, objects have been grouped already.
      * @return {Object} thisArg
      */
-    initialize: function(objects, options) {
+    initialize: function(objects, options, isAlreadyGrouped) {
       options = options || { };

+      this._objects = [];
+      // if objects enclosed in a group have been grouped already,
+      // we cannot change properties of objects.
+      // Thus we need to set options to group without objects,
+      // because delegatedProperties propagate to objects.
+      isAlreadyGrouped && this.callSuper('initialize', options);
+
       this._objects = objects || [];
       for (var i = this._objects.length; i--; ) {
         this._objects[i].group = this;
@@ -67,15 +75,20 @@
       if (options.originX) {
         this.originX = options.originX;
       }
-
       if (options.originY) {
         this.originY = options.originY;
       }

-      this._calcBounds();
-      this._updateObjectsCoords();
-
-      this.callSuper('initialize', options);
+      if (isAlreadyGrouped) {
+        // do not change coordinate of objects enclosed in a group,
+        // because objects coordinate system have been group coodinate system already.
+        this._updateObjectsCoords(true);
+      }
+      else {
+        this._calcBounds();
+        this._updateObjectsCoords();
+        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
+      }

       this.setCoords();
       this.saveCoords();
@@ -83,15 +96,28 @@

     /**
      * @private
+     * @param {Boolean} [skipCoordsChange] if true, coordinates of objects enclosed in a group do not change
      */
-    _updateObjectsCoords: function() {
-      this.forEachObject(this._updateObjectCoords, this);
+    _updateObjectsCoords: function(skipCoordsChange) {
+      for (var i = this._objects.length; i--; ){
+        this._updateObjectCoords(this._objects[i], skipCoordsChange);
+      }
     },

     /**
      * @private
+     * @param {Object} object
+     * @param {Boolean} [skipCoordsChange] if true, coordinates of object dose not change
      */
-    _updateObjectCoords: function(object) {
+    _updateObjectCoords: function(object, skipCoordsChange) {
+      // do not display corners of objects enclosed in a group
+      object.__origHasControls = object.hasControls;
+      object.hasControls = false;
+
+      if (skipCoordsChange) {
+        return;
+      }
+
       var objectLeft = object.getLeft(),
           objectTop = object.getTop(),
           center = this.getCenterPoint();
@@ -102,12 +128,7 @@
         left: objectLeft - center.x,
         top: objectTop - center.y
       });
-
       object.setCoords();
-
-      // do not display corners of objects enclosed in a group
-      object.__origHasControls = object.hasControls;
-      object.hasControls = false;
     },

     /**
@@ -558,7 +579,7 @@
   fabric.Group.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
     fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function(enlivenedObjects) {
       delete object.objects;
-      callback && callback(new fabric.Group(enlivenedObjects, object));
+      callback && callback(new fabric.Group(enlivenedObjects, object, true));
     });
   };

diff --git a/test/unit/group.js b/test/unit/group.js
index 306a8ed..9a95c8b 100644
--- a/test/unit/group.js
+++ b/test/unit/group.js
@@ -16,6 +16,13 @@
     return new fabric.Group([ rect1, rect2 ], {strokeWidth: 0});
   }

+  function makeGroupWith2ObjectsWithOpacity() {
+    var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({ top: 100, left: 100, width: 30, height: 10, strokeWidth: 0, opacity: 0.5 }),
+        rect2 = new fabric.Rect({ top: 120, left: 50, width: 10, height: 40, strokeWidth: 0, opacity: 0.8 });
+
+    return new fabric.Group([ rect1, rect2 ], {strokeWidth: 0});
+  }
+
   function makeGroupWith4Objects() {
     var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({ top: 100, left: 100, width: 30, height: 10 }),
         rect2 = new fabric.Rect({ top: 120, left: 50, width: 10, height: 40 }),
@@ -363,7 +370,7 @@ test('toObject without default values', function() {
   });

   asyncTest('fromObject', function() {
-    var group = makeGroupWith2Objects();
+    var group = makeGroupWith2ObjectsWithOpacity();

     ok(typeof fabric.Group.fromObject == 'function');
     var groupObject = group.toObject();
@@ -375,6 +382,9 @@ test('toObject without default values', function() {

       ok(newGroupFromObject instanceof fabric.Group);

+      deepEqual(objectFromOldGroup.objects[0], objectFromNewGroup.objects[0]);
+      deepEqual(objectFromOldGroup.objects[1], objectFromNewGroup.objects[1]);
+
       // delete `objects` arrays, since `assertHashEqual` fails to compare them for equality
       delete objectFromOldGroup.objects;
       delete objectFromNewGroup.objects;
```